# ocr engine ia better made in java or Matlab

Tags: java, android, eclipse, matlab

we are making an android application where the text retrieved from the image is to be integrated with other apps of an android phone.
we are making this application using Eclipse IDE and the gui and the integration part is in java and xml, which is done
We now are starting with the OCR engine and are confused about making it in java or Matlab.So please help us out as to using which language is better in accordance to the IDE and the rst of the project.

Comment: I don't believe you can develop android apps with Matlab.